# Jquery get data attribute for input

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I use this plugin: https://github.com/irfan/jquery-star-rating

I have html:

```
<div class="container">
<input type="radio" data-id="attr-1" name="example" class="rating" value="1" />
<input type="radio" data-id="attr-2" name="example" class="rating" value="2" />
<input type="radio" data-id="attr-3" name="example" class="rating" value="3" />
<input type="radio" data-id="attr-4" name="example" class="rating" value="4" />
<input type="radio" data-id="attr-5" name="example" class="rating" value="5" />
</div>
```

I use ajax:

```
$('.container').rating(function(vote, event){
     $.get(document.URL, {vote: vote, attr: $(this).data('id')});
});
```

> ```
> $(this).data('id')
> ```

not working. How I can fix? In documentation of the plugin I don't see How I can get data attribute.

Comment: `this` is your container, which doesn't have a data attribute.

Comment: And how fix?///

Comment: [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) is what you want

Comment: in event target I get `<a href=""></a>..`

Comment: PS: Why would you use a 6 year old rating when there are newer ones that are actually updated

Comment: Can you give me example?

Comment: instead of `$('.container').rating()`, have you tried using `$('.container input').rating()`?

Comment: I think this will return a `data('id')`.
`$(event.target).closest('.container').find('input[value="'+vote+'"]').data('id')`

Comment: @PhilippSander `this` inside a function is a callback function itself not a container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not personally use a 6 year old rating code, but you can try this:

```
$('.container').rating(function(vote, event){
   $.get(document.URL, {
         vote: vote, 
         attr: $(".container>.rating["value="+vote+"]").data('id')
   });
});
```

or just

```
attr: "attr-"+vote
```